# SQL Server insert after delete Trigger error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to insert a row into a new table when a row is deleted from the original table but I keep getting the below error when i run a delete on a record.

I read error message details and it says it has something to do with type of data cannot be inserted but I don't understand this since I copied exact table structure that it was deleted from to be inserted to.

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Procedure DeleteEmpTR, Line 5
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.DeletedEmp
FROM Original.Employees
WHERE 1=2;

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.DeleteEmpTR ON dbo.Employees
AFTER DELETE
AS

INSERT INTO dbo.DeletedEmp
SELECT d.col1, d.col2, ...
FROM deleted d
WHERE empid not in (SELECT empid FROM inserted);

/*
--tests
DELETE FROM dbo.Employees
WHERE empid = 9
SELECT * FROM dbo.DeletedEmp; 
*/
```

Comment: It would seem that `Original.Employees` and `dbo.Employees` do not have the same column definitions.

Comment: **never ever** use `select *`. Always explicitly list the columns. Do that and your code will probably work

Comment: Side note: If your trigger really does look like what you've shown (it's just an `AFTER DELETE` trigger) then the `inserted` check doesn't make sense. It will *always* be empty for a delete trigger.

Comment: The first thing you do is copy all the employee records to the deleted table. So you start out showing all the employees as having been deleted. What is the purpose of that? If the DeletedEmp table has the same PK, the trigger insert will fail. Then change the trigger Insert statement: `insert into DeletedEmp( <list of columns> ) select <list of columns> from Deleted;`. My guess is that your list of columns in the select statement does not match the defined list of columns in the DeletedEmp table. No need to check Inserted -- it contains nothing in a delete trigger.

Comment: Got it all sorted. Instead of SELECT INTO I used an explicit CREATE TABLE. may have had some fuss about the identity column. Also removed the unnecessary WHERE clause. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Your `INSERT INTO` also does not have an explicit column list. These kinds of things return and bite you when you least want them to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should check both of your tables `Employees` and `DeletedEmp` columns have same column data-type. (data-definition)
- Check any columns with `char and varchar`  have same length. `Char(n)` and `VarChar(n)`, where *n* is the length of string.

Error `String or binary data would be truncated` is generally when length of the string to be inserted is **more** than the target's table column can accommodate.